Can I use promises to speed up a computational process so that I can create parallelism in it?
I have intense CPU consuming computations that need to be done and then written to file. I know that I can use promises to create parallelism in writing and reading files, since it is an I/O operation. But can I use promises to create parallelism in computations over promises even though there isn't an asynchronous operation?
If I can't use promises for this, what can I do so that this operation doesn't block the thread?
For example, a random time consuming calculation to create raw data. And it is written to file like this.
This function takes 9-10ms to complete in my computer.
const fs = require('node:fs');

async function main() {
    console.time('Write file');

    let content = 'number,number,number,number,number\n';

    function getRandomInt() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() + 1000) * 1000000000000000000000);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i<1400;i++){
        content += `${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()}\n`;
    }

    fs.writeFile('./fakeData.csv', content, err => {
        // file written successfully
        console.log("File written successfully!");
        console.timeEnd('Write file');
    });
}

main();

So, I tried to speed up the process by dividing it to chunks in promises.
This function takes 7-8ms to complete.
const fs = require('node:fs');

async function main() {
    console.time('Write file');

    let content = 'number,number,number,number,number\n';

    function getRandomInt() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() + 1000) * 1000000000000000000000);
    }

    const write200Line = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let content = '';
        for(let i = 0; i<200;i++){
            content += `${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()},${getRandomInt() * getRandomInt()}\n`;
        }
        resolve(content);
    });

    const values = await Promise.all([write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line]);
    values.forEach(val => {
        content += val;
    });

    fs.writeFile('./fakeData.csv', content, err => {
        // file written successfully
        console.log("File written successfully!");
        console.timeEnd('Write file');
    });
}

main();

I couldn't understand why it is faster, even though there is no asynchronous operation in the promises. I write to the file at the end of the function without any parallelism.
Although I see some improvement with this setup, contrary simple logic, it doesn't decrease the time when I divide it further like write100Line with more promises.
And I couldn't understand why I see improvement when I divide it to 7 chunks rather than 1 for loop, but can't see any improvement on 14 chunks.

It's not related to promises but rather to CON string format in V8, details are here: V8 and big string comparison performance affected a lot by hashing the strings?

using Array.push then join should be much faster

"I know that I can use promises to create parallelism in writing and reading files, since it is an I/O operation" - no. It's IO being asynchronous that allows you to concurrently write and read files at the same time. Promises are not the cause of this. Promises are only a tool that helps with managing asynchronous results.

"Promise.all([write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line, write200Line])" - that's useless. You have only one promise that's writing 200 lines. There's a single loop with 200 iterations that is executed once, fulfilling the single promise. Promise.all is waiting for the same promise multiple times.

PARALLEL processing (be it a code-execution or not) gets remarkably often misunderstood, even at universities. What is NOT parallelism - a latency masking (like during (non)blocking calls to perform I/O), an uncoordinated, independently flowing just-CONCURRENT processing (with no warranty as to when such uncoordinated code-execution paths actually finish), a plain-SERIAL processing (one-step-after-another) - neither of these are true parallelism. Starting from this, confusions get clearer. Sync-barriers are only a side-step to enforce common one ending of otherwise a just-CONCURRENT execution

More details on overhead-respecting, resources-aware Amdahl's Law, which helps understand where, if at all, any speedups can materialise : https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 Latency-masking ( be it in file-I/O, network-I/O or in GPU SMX SIMD-threads scheduler ) can help by de-SERIAL-ising really paid waiting times by interleaved ( just-CONCURRENT ) execution, where waiting times get masked and some final sync-barrier finally enforce dumb blocking-"coordinated" exit from such pseudo-"parallel" section ( all wait for a slowest member, infinitely in worst-case ). Not PARALLEL, sorry.
